# Where is this statement written - "त्वमेव माता च पिता त्वमेव...."

Tags: scripture, sanskrit, reference-request

There is a popular Sanskrit Stanza
त्वमेव माता च पिता त्वमेव,
त्वमेव बन्धुश्च सखा त्वमेव।
त्वमेव विद्या च द्रविणं त्वमेव,
त्वमेव सर्वम् मम देवदेवं।

What is the source for it ? And for whom it is addressed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioned in Skanda Purana with slight changes.

Sri Skand Purana 1.1.7.:

> 8. **The sages who were desirous of eulogizing Maheśvara,** the sinless one, eulogized with very great eagerness and respect by means of excellent words recorded in the Vedas.
>
> The sages said.:
>
> .
>
> **त्वमेव माता च पिता त्वमेव त्वमेव बंधुश्च सखा त्वमे । त्वमीश्वरो वेदविदेकरूपो महानुभावैः परिचिंत्यमानः ॥ १० ॥**
>
> **त्वमात्मा सर्वभूतानामेको ज्योतिरिवैधसाम् । सर्वं भवति यस्मात्त्वत्तस्मात्सर्वोऽसि नित्यदा ॥ ११ ॥**
>
> **यस्माच्च संभवत्येतत्तस्माच्छंभुरिति प्रभुः ॥ १२ ॥**
>
> 10. **You are our mother. You alone are our father. You are our kinsman. You alone are our friend. You alone are īśvara. You are conversant with the Vedas. You are always meditated upon by persons of great magnanimity.**
>
> 11-12. **You are the immanent Soul of all living beings, like flame of all fuel. Since everything takes its origin from you, you are forever Sarva. The lord is called Śaṃbhu because Śaṃ (happiness) takes its origin from him.**

I hope this helps. Prd..

Comment: Is it referring to Bhagwan Shiva ?

Comment: Yes, It's mentioned in verse no. 8 only.

Comment: Is such a thing mentioned anywhere else also  ? For Vishnu or Krishna ? The statement needn't be exactly the same, but should imply the same thing.

Comment: Yes, It's called Pandava Gita. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14786/20968.

Answer (score 3):

This is from [Sarnagati Gadayam](https://archive.org/details/periyavachangadyatraya/page/n15/mode/1up?view=theater) composed by Shri Ramanujacharya, this is addressed to Lord Narayana and his wife Laxmi:

> [image]
> [image]